# change .htaccess of idx feed so url shows the domain name

Tags: .htaccess

I have idx feeds from idxbroker.com, but the url the provide is not such a clean url.

`http://myrealestatewebsite.idxbroker.com/i/xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxx`

Is there a way to change the url with htacess, so 
when visitor type `http://www.myrealestatewebsite.com/xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxx`
is shows content of `http://myrealestatewebsite.idxbroker.com/i/xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxx`
Do i have to change my links also? a way that will benefit SEO as all are hosted in the main website `http://www.myrealestatewebsite.com`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, try this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /i/([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/i/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /i/$1 [L]
```

Once that is there you can change your links to without `/i/` at front. However till the time you don't change first `301` rule will take care of it.

Comment: What was your original in your browser? Is this .htaccess placed in DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess?

Comment: using google chrome- Yes in the root.. added to htaccess that was there before  - How about this?

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^i/([^/]*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]`

Comment: See edited code. Make sure to place these rules before your existing rules. If possible post your current .htaccess in your question. What URL are you entering in your browser?